# Is this duplicating a Maven dependency in a multi module project (i.e Spring)?

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, maven

Here is the simple situation breakdown and I'd like to know if I'm doing this optimally or if there is a better convention. I have created a dummy project just for learning purposes.

I have created a multi module Maven project. Simply the parent POM, with two sibling child POMS, one being a service layer, and the other being a web layer.

The end result goal is to have a fully functioning WAR in the Web project's target folder, that I can simply deploy into a Tomcat.

Here is where I am not clear: 
- Both the Service project, and the Web project need to use Spring. The Service project needs to use Spring simply for it's dependency injection purpose. I need to take a simple Dog class, and auto-inject it into the DogService object. That's all working fine. 
- Then I need to auto-inject a DogService object into a Dog controller. The Dog controller exists within the Web project in the multi module structure. This is also working fine, because I have declared a dependency in the Web project for the Service project, therefore all Service JARs are included in the final built WAR, from the web project.

1) Is there a way to simply declare a Spring dependency for both child projects without having to declare the dependencies in each child POM.xml? I just want to make sure I'm not duplicating resources. I believe the way to do this is just to declare the dependency in the Parent POM.xml.

2) If I do #1 above ^, is this the optimal way of creating the project? In essence, the WEB module is the one that contains all the final jars, and in essence it's almost as if the SERVICE project doesn't even exist in Tomcat. As far as Tomcat 'knows', all there is, is a bunch of JAR files containing classes, some of them having been written in my WEB module, and some of them having been written in the SERVICE module, all of which is irrelevant to the production/Tomcat environment. True or false?

Thanks!

Comment: If this is new development, it's generally preferable to go for a standalone jar with Spring Boot instead of deploying into an external container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to simply declare a Spring dependency for both child projects without having to declare the dependencies in each child POM.xml? I just want to make sure I'm not duplicating resources. I believe the way to do this is just to declare the dependency in the Parent POM.xml.

Maven is quite intelligent about dependency management and will not "duplicate" resources--it caches each dependency once* and manages the classpath so that all of the projects that you work with share the same jars. In general, declare dependencies in the modules where they're needed; don't clutter up modules or *especially* parents with random pieces just to avoid occasionally re-specifying a dependency. This is like hauling your boat trailer on your daily commute because you occasionally go to the lake.

Keep in mind that dependencies are *transitive*, so that if `service-module` depends on `spring-web` (does it really, or are you spamming dependencies?), if `web-module` depends on `service-module` it will pull in the dependency as well without having to repeat yourself.

> If I do #1 above ^, is this the optimal way of creating the project?

No, it isn't. Be minimalist about your dependencies: If you need it, include it, but don't add dependencies "defensively". This will just bloat your deployment and slow down builds, along with adding opportunities for problems like version mismatches.

> As far as Tomcat 'knows', all there is, is a bunch of JAR files containing classes, some of them having been written in my WEB module, and some of them having been written in the SERVICE module, all of which is irrelevant to the production/Tomcat environment. True or false?

Mostly false. In a war, your top-level project (`web-module`) has its classes directly in the archive, and dependencies are embedded as jar file inside it. Tomcat does *not* distinguish between `service-module` and your Spring and other dependencies, however.

Better still would be using Spring Boot's standalone jar and embedded container features--Boot will take care of packaging up the jars you need into a single runnable file that doesn't need external support.

*Release dependencies only, but snapshots aren't relevant here.

Comment: Right, Tomcat does not distinguish. Hence, because MY service-module classes are dependent on some spring classes (like to import @autowired and other spring specific dependencies), I do not understand if I can simply have the final dependency jars in my web-module target, or do they need to be in the service-module POM dependencies as well? Because when I go to compile my service-module, and I don't have Spring as a dependency, it throws. This is where I am getting confused. In a perfect end result, I would simply only have the Spring dependencies in my web-module's WAR archives.